# How to read or When to read the DTC (Fault code) from OBD device?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, obd-ii

I am developing an iOS app which enables me to store information of cars. I'm using an OBD-2 Bluetooth device to interact with my app.

There is a scenario where I need the value DTC or Diagnostic Trouble Code to be stored. Some blogs suggest that the value of DTC should only be fetched when the vehicle ignition is ON and shouldn't do it when the engine is running.

I need to know why that is an issue. What are the factors which needs to be noted while reading those DTC values?

Answer (score 1):

In AUTOSAR artitecture the value of DTC is stored in Non-Volatile Memory Manager (NvM).

So, I sugest it will be not an issues if you read it when the engine is running.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the stored Diagnostic Trouble Codes will not be a problem while the engine is running, worse case situation the module you are querying will return you a negative response code.  You will need the ignition on as most cars require ignition on for the modules to be alive.